# Be $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable, such that there is no $x \in [0,1]$ with $f(x) = f'(x) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

**Question** : Be $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable, such that there is no $x \in [0,1]$ with $f(x) = f'(x) = 0$.. Proof that set $Z = \{x \in [0,1] : f(x) = 0\}$ is finite.

My answer:

> How f is a derivative function, we have that is continuous in your domain [0,1]. Let's supposse that $f(x) = f'(x)\neq 0$ and that $Z \subset [0,1]$ is infinity. How Z is infinity and bounded, exists a subsequence of elements of Z that converge for some $x_0$. Knowing this, if $f'(0) < 0 < f'(1)$ then exists $x \in (0,1)$ such that $f'(x) = 0$. But We had suppose that $f(x) = f'(x) \neq 0$ which is contradition.

That's correct?

Comment: Your question is not clearly stated. Can you double check the problem's source and repost it or paste it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your contradiction follows from three assumptions, so no, it's not correct.

The weird part is you have a part of a valid solution in the middle of your solution when you let $x_0$ denote a limit point of $Z$ (which you've proven exists after assuming $Z$ is infinite).  To finish, you need to show $$f(x_0)=0=f'(x_0)$$